# Convert listDirectory map from Haskell do notation

Tags: haskell

Consider this Haskell script that appends an exclamation mark to every path in a directory:

```hs
import System.Directory

mapPaths paths = map (++ "!") paths

transformAll = do
    paths <- listDirectory "/"
    print $ mapPaths paths

main = transformAll
```

How can I convert this to a chain of bind operations from left to right while still using the function `mapPaths` as is?

I would like to understand how to compose a function that would look kind of like:

```
doSomething :: [String] => IO [String]
doSomething paths = ???

transformAll = listDirectory "/" >>= doSomething >>= print
```

Where `doSomething` has this signature and makes use of `mapPaths`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<-` desugars into `>>=` and a lambda, like this:

```
transformAll = listDirectory "/" >>= \paths -> print $ mapPaths paths
```

You can then write the function you want like this:

```
doSomething :: [String] -> IO [String]
doSomething paths = return $ mapPaths paths
```

By the way, since `[String]` is an argument type and not a constraint, you use a little arrow after it, not a big arrow. Also, IMO, having `doSomething` at all just makes things less clear for no reason (since it doesn't need to do any IO operations but now has IO in its type anyway). You could write `transformAll = listDirectory "/" >>= print . mapPaths` or `transformAll = listDirectory "/" >>= (mapPaths <&> print)` instead to avoid it (note the latter needs `<&>` from `Data.Functor`).

Comment: Ah, thank you!  It's the return function. You say <- desugars into >>= and a lambda.  But if you define that named function, couldn't you say that <- desugars into >>= and the return call all the same?

Comment: @EdI ...No? Your named function introduces a second `>>=`, whereas there was only one before, so the `return` is only needed to cancel out the second `>>=`. Desugaring never produces a new `return`; when one is needed, you always have to write it.

Comment: I see.  I do want to introduce the second `>>=`, just to understand how the chain would work.  And I guess that's what the return is for, when you don't have a real IO action.

Comment: *this* [`(<&>) :: Functor f => f a -> (a -> b) -> f b`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--38--62-)?

Comment: @WillNess Yes, why?

Comment: I couldn't make it work in my head for some reason. my bad. `(<&>) = flip (<$>) = flip (.) = (>>>)` here, so it does work.

Answer (score 2):

Joseph Sible has already shown how to desugar the do-notation into lambdas and proposed one solution using more powerful combinators, so I won't rehash that ground. I do want to point out as an aside, though, that `(=<<)`, a "flipped" version of `(>>=)`, often makes code easier to read, by letting you compose functions in the same textual order as you would in non-monadic code.

Imagine, for example, that instead of

```
 listDirectory "/" :: IO [String]
```

you had some other function that just produced a non-IO list of strings:

```
compute "/" :: [String]
```

To mapPaths and then print this, you might write

```
print . mapPaths $ compute "/"
```

Using `(=<<)` instead of `(>>=)` lets you keep this basic structure, just changing which operators are used, emphasizing the compositional nature more than the monadic operations:

```
print . mapPaths =<< listDirectory "/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Like all monads, `IO` is also a functor, which means you can write

```
import System.Directory

mapPaths :: [FilePath] -> [FilePath]
mapPaths paths = map (++ "!") paths

-- Conceptually, printing is not part of the transformation of the paths;
-- leave it out of the definition.
transformAll :: IO [FilePath]
transformAll =  mapPaths <$> listDirectory "/"

main = transformAll >>= print
```